# How to send Header and body soap request for android 6.0

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I had header and body in my soap request and
[Soap request looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDapn.png)
Here is my complete java class with AsyncTask

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rewads_screen1, container, false);
    mAvailableReward = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Bt_AvailableReward);
    mClaimedReward = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Bt_ClaimedReward);
    mExpiredDisqualifiedReward = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Bt_ExpiredDisqualifiedReward);

    mExpiredDisqualifiedReward.setEnabled(false);
    mBT_ClaimItNw1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Bt_ClaimItNow1);
    mIV_ArrowNext1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.IV_NextArrow1);
    mBT_ViewRewardTracker1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Bt_viewRewardTracker1);
    mIV_ArrowNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rewardScreenLayout, new Reward_screen_fragment2()).commit();
        }
    });
    mBT_ClaimItNw1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), RewardConfiirmation.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mBT_ViewRewardTracker1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rewardScreenLayout, new CongratulationsFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
    mLoginbean.setLoginType("CNUM");
    mLoginbean.setBillPhone("103488321");
    mLoginbean.setBillPhoneFormatted("format");
    mLoginbean.setConnectionID(77093196);
    mLoginbean.setCreateUser("WebUser");
    mLoginbean.setCustomerID(18334267);
    mLoginbean.setCustomerName("Steven Cohen");
    mLoginbean.setCustomerZipCode("349949502");
    mLoginbean.setEmailAddress("gjh56tys6y");
    mLoginbean.setEmailSaved(true);
    mLoginbean.setLoginProductTypes("heloo");
    mLoginbean.setLoginSuccessful(true);
    mLoginbean.setLoginTried(true);
    mLoginbean.setZipCode("h3hd");
    mLoginbean.setRedemptionIDProductGroup("sdfasdf");
    mLoginbean.setOptIn("false");
    mLoginbean.setRedemptionID("gdfgj");
    mLoginbean.setProductName("dfgj");
    mClaimedReward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, Methodname);
            PropertyInfo tabProp = new PropertyInfo();
            tabProp.setName("AttLogins");
            tabProp.setValue(new SoapObject(NameSpace, "AttLogin").
                    addProperty("LoginType","CNUM").
                    addProperty("BillPhone","hgh").
                    addProperty("BillPhoneFormatted", "fgf").
                    addProperty("CreateUser","fg").
                    addProperty("ConnectionID",77093196).
                    addProperty("CustomerID",39).
                    addProperty("CustomerZipCode","fgfg").
                    addProperty("LoginTried", true).
                    addProperty("LoginSuccessful",true).
                    addProperty("OptIn","sdfg").
                    addProperty("CustomerName","fg").
                    addProperty("EmailAddress","fg").
                    addProperty("EmailSaved", false).
                    addProperty("LoginProductTypes","fg").
                    addProperty("RedemptionID", "fg").
                    addProperty("RedemptionIDProductGroup", "fg").
                    addProperty("ProductName","df").
                    addProperty("ZipCode", "dfd"));
            request.addProperty(tabProp);

            new getReedemedProductInfo(request,Methodname).execute();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

class getReedemedProductInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject> {
    SoapObject mPostData;
    String mMethod;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    public getReedemedProductInfo(SoapObject postData,
                                  String method) {
        mPostData = postData;
        mMethod = method;
    }
    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... params) {;
        Log.d("Request", mPostData.toString());
        String SOAP_ACTION = NameSpace+mMethod;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.headerOut=new Element[1];
        envelope.headerOut[0]=buildAuthHeader();
        envelope.bodyOut=mPostData;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
           // Log.d("envelop",envelope.toString());
            androidHttpTransport.call(Soap_Action, envelope);
            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof  SoapFault) {
                final SoapFault sf = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
                 //response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Log.d("Soap fault",sf.toString());
            }
            else {
                //response = resultsRequestSOAP;
                Log.d("response", "" + response.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("errorResponse", e.getMessage() + response);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Validating ,Please wait..");
       dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject soapObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(soapObject);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
private Element buildAuthHeader() {
    Element h = new Element().createElement(NameSpace, "AuthHeader");
    Element username = new Element().createElement(NameSpace, "SessionKey");

    username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
    h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);

    return h;
}

   /*String s = "AuthenticationKey";
        if (soapObject != null) {
            SoapObject root = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);
            String property = root.getProperty("AuthenticationKey").toString();
            System.out.println("Authenticationkey " + property);


        } else {
            System.out.println("response is empty");
        }*/
  /* header = new Element[1];
        header[0] = new Element().createElement(NameSpace, "AuthHeader");
        Element sessionkey = new Element().createElement(NameSpace, "SessionKey");
        sessionkey.addChild(Node.TEXT, ("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
        header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, sessionkey);*/
```

}

I am getting a soap fault as in errorSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index

Am i missing any thing .I am not sure my header and body are correct framed.Please suggest something useful..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please some one replay fast its so urgent for me to deliver build

Comment: Y no one are there to help me on stackoverflow